# Unable to create scratch org with Functions feature?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, salesforce-functions

I've installed the latest CLI versions for SFDX and SF, but still when I try to create a scratch org with mentioned commands. I'm getting the below error:

ERROR running force:org:create:  Functions is not a valid Features value.

My Project-scratch-def.json file >>>

```
{
  "orgName": "Functions Recipes",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Functions", "EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

Also, SFDX and SF version >>>
sfdx-cli/7.174.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.17.1
@salesforce/cli/1.51.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.17.1

I've also verified that the plugin is installed.

Please help if anyone has faced something similar and resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an Org with Functions feature enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error, it looks like you are NOT connecting to a DevHub org that has the Functions feature enabled.

To use functions within your scratch org, you will need to access to a Functions Enabled Org.

**How to get access to Functions Org?**

You can obtain a Trial edition of Functions org on first come first serve basis for 30 days using this [link](https://functions.salesforce.com/signups/).

If you need to enable in your Production orgs contact your Salesforce Account executive.

Note that you can run functions locally too without needing a license. Check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/11/getting-started-with-salesforce-functions-locally-no-license-required) blogpost for more details.